# About Mersenne Twister generator's period

Tags: random, mersenne-twister

I have read that Mersenne Twister generator has a period of 2¹⁹⁹³⁷ - 1, but I'm confused about why can that be possible. I see [this implementation](http://en.literateprograms.org/Mersenne_twister_%28C%29) of the Mersenne Twister algorithm and in the first comment it clearly says that it produces values in the range 0 to 2³² - 1. Therefore, after it has produced 2³² - 1 different random numbers, it will necessarily come back to the starting point (the seed), so the period can be at maximum 2³² - 1.

Also (and tell me if I'm wrong, please), a computer can't hold the number (2¹⁹⁹³⁷ - 1) ~ 4.3×10⁶⁰⁰¹, at least in a single block of memory. What am I missing here?

Comment: MT19937 has 624 bytes of state so u.it can fit in single block. And this seed wrapping you are talking about only applies to linear congruential generators, which MT isn't.

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion stems from thinking that the output number and the internal state of a PRNG have to be the same thing.

Some very old PRNGs used to do this, such as Linear Congruental Generators. In those generators, the current output was fed back into the generator for the next step.

However, most PRNGS, including the Mersenne Twister, work from a much larger state, which it updates and uses to generate a 32-bit number (it doesn't really matter which order this is done in for the purposes of this answer).

In fact, the Mersenne Twister does indeed store 624 times 32-bit values, and that is 19968 bits, enough to contain the very long period that you are wondering about. The values are handled separately (as unsigned 32-bit integers), not treated as one giant number in a single-step calculation. The 32-bit random number you get from the output is *related* to this state, but does not determine the next number by itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong at

> Therefore, after it has produced 2³² - 1 different random numbers, it
>   will necessarily come back to the starting point (the seed)...

That's right that the next number can be the same with one of the number already generated, but the internal state of the random number generator will not be the same. (Noone told you that every number in the range 2³² - 1 will be generated at the 2³² - 1th step.) So there's no bijection between the random number generated and the internal state of the generator. The random number generated can be calculated from the state but you don't even have to do it. You can step the internal state also without creating the random number.

And of course, the computer doesn't store the whole number sequence. It calculates the random number from the internal state. Consider a number sequence like 1, -1, 1, -1 ... you can generate the Nth number without storing number of N elements.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I think I have not been clear enough or I just didn't understand at all your answer. Let me explain with a very simple example. Let's say we have the following set of numbers: N = {1, 2, 3} and we have a PRNG whose period is 5, it is to say, independently of its internal state it can output at maximum 5 different numbers (this is what I understand by "period"). If we apply this PRNG to N, how can it produce 5 different elements if N has only 3? Now replace "3" by "2³² - 1" and "5" by "2¹⁹⁹³⁷ - 1"; this is my real doubt.

Comment: Or maybe you are saying that MT19937 can have 2¹⁹⁹³⁷ - 1 different states (not necessarily 2¹⁹⁹³⁷ - 1 different outputs)? Then I would understand everything, because as you say there's no bijection between the output number and the internal state of the generator.

Comment: @DanielMuñozParsapoormoghadam I think you are confused about what is meant by "period". The period defines when the sequences will repeat, not the "maximum different numbers" it can produce. So using your example PRNG, it will produce 5 numbers, each of which are in the set {1, 2, 3}, then it will keep on producing those same 5 numbers over and over.

Comment: @DanielMuñozParsapoormoghadam And yes, MT19937 can have that many states. Internally the state is stored in 624 32-bit words. 624 * 32 = 19968 bits, out of which 31 are not used, giving you 19937 used bits.